Isometric automorphisms of the ring of symmetric functions
I was trying to understand how special the $\omega$ involution on the ring of symmetric functions $\Lambda$ or $\Lambda^n$ (restriction to $n$ variables, just in case if by some magic, the situation is different there) is. I know how it corresponds to tensoring by the sign-alternating irrep. However, it's still a somewhat arbitrary choice to me. The inner product seemed more natural arising from character orthonormality of irreps of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. So I started looking for candidates $\omega'$ which can replace $\omega$, which means:

$\omega'$ is a  algebra automorphism of $\Lambda$
$\omega'$ is an isometry under the usual inner product defined by declaring Schur polynomials orthonormal.

The two obvious candidates which fulfill the roles are the identity and $\omega$. But are there others? I feel there aren't, but I don't know how to go about proving this. The tactic I had in mind was that I want to make sure my automorphism respects the Littlewood-Richardson rule (trying to exploit the obvious niceness of the inner product w.r.t Schur polynomials), but the coefficients are pretty difficult to deal with.

There is at least one other isometric algebra automorphism of $\Lambda$: The "degree flip", which sends each homogeneous symmetric function $f$ of degree $n$ to $\left(-1\right)^n f$. (This one works even for finitely many variables.) You can also compose this with $\omega$ to get a fourth automorphism. Are there others? I guess this will depend on the base ring.

If the base ring $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$, then it is not hard to see that any isometric algebra isomorphism $f : \Lambda \to \Lambda$ must send each power-sum symmetric function $p_n$ to $\kappa_n p_n$ for some $\kappa_n \in \left{+1,-1\right}$. Thus, the choice of $f$ boils down to choosing an infinite sequence of signs $\kappa_1, \kappa_2, \kappa_3, \ldots$. But most of these choices will probably not lead to $f$'s that preserve the integer-coefficients property, so they won't work over $\mathbb{Z}$. Interesting question!

(You get $\omega$ by taking $\kappa_n = \left(-1\right)^{n-1}$, and you get the degree flip by taking $\kappa_n = \left(-1\right)^n$.)

Ah, I see. Only the four automorphisms mentioned in my first comment exist over $\mathbb{Z}$. The way to see this is by extending the base ring to $\mathbb{Q}$ and normalizing the signs $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ to be $1$ (using convolution of automorphisms), and then arguing that the smallest $i$ satisfying $\kappa_i = -1$ cannot be larger than $2$ or else the Newton identities would contain uncancellable denominators.

Wow, that is impressive. I'd say, for my purposes of trying to call the $\omega$ transform 'natural', this probably suffices. Thanks!
That being said, what happens over other rings might be interesting anyway.
